# Copying and pasting nonzero rows and adjacent cells

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, copy-paste, vba

I am dealing with a lot of GIS metadata that I am importing into Excel, with many rows and columns of blank or zero values. I am trying to take data like this:

(Left Column is the name, columns to the right are the values associated with that name)

[image]

and by only selecting the columns that have a value, end up with a new set of tables showing the nonzero rows and its corresponding name to the left:

[image]

I have tried doing it by filtering the data in a table so that it only shows nonzero values, copying that column and the far left column and pasting it onto a new sheet.  This is easy if I only have a few columns, but given the amount I have it is very painstaking.  I have to filter each column separately because the rows in each column may or may not have blanks or zeros depending on the column.

Can the LOOKUP function be used for this, or would using VBA be better?

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables?

Comment: I wouldn't do the double-step of importing into Excel and then trying to manipulate. I'd use VBA to read the XML file and write a sheet as you want it. If you could edit your question to show sample XML then we could help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why can't use 2 simple loops (rows, columns)??
i suppose that the data start from "A1", I count rows and columns and play this code.

```
Sub tras()
Dim lastRw As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim ResultRow As Integer
ResultRow = 20 '1th row for result
lastRw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
Set rgn = Range("A1", Cells(lastRw, lastRw))
For x = 2 To lastCol
    For y = 1 To lastRw
        If Cells(y, x) <> "" Then
            Cells(ResultRow, 1) = Cells(y, 1).Value
            Cells(ResultRow, 2) = Cells(y, x).Value
            ResultRow = ResultRow + 1
        End If
    Next y
    ResultRow = ResultRow + 1
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  A bit simpler than I thought it would be.  I had to add an And on the If statement to catch 0's as well.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A filtering in a similar case can be performed with array formulas such as in the example below.

See an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlyUN.jpg

(I cannot post images yet - please edit my post so that the image is integrated)

To use it select range E1:E6, write the shown formula and press ctrl+shift+enter.

The logic is as follows:

1) based on range B1:B6 create two vectors: 1 with row numbers of each row which simply is a v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6} in this case and a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs for each row with TRUE if a row is nonempty and FALSe if empty: in this case it is v2 = {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}.

2) multiply v1 and v2 element wise which gives us vector v3 = {1,0,3,4,0,0}

3) using SMALL function extract values from the smallest to the largest using COUNTBLANK function to skip all the zeros (their number is equal to number of blanks) - ROW function used on range E1:E6 serves as our iterator in SMALL function

4) after point 3) you end up with row numbers of non-empty cells based on range B1:B6, now you have to call INDEX function to extract values from range A1:A6

5) add IFERROR on top of everything so that it returns "" when going out of SMALL's input array's range

To assign values in column F simply use INDEX + MATCH (I encourage everyone to forget about *LOOKUP).

What you end up here with is something that I think addresses your core problem. If you want to make it all "draggable" or "fillable", use it on ranges other that beginning with 1 or put it all in setup row after row rather than column after column, you'll have to make some modifications to the formulas used here but the logic will be the same.